# Trying to get glyphicon touching the input bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I am trying to get the search icon to appear touching the input form so it can be on the same line when I scale down.

The problem is there is a large gap between the button and input field and that stacks when you make screen smaller.

here is the code:

```
<form class="navbar-left" role="search" method=post action={{ url_for('search') }}>

  <div class="form-group form-inline">

    <div class="input-group input-lg">

      {{ render_field(form.search, placeholder='Buscar') }}

    </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about something like this?

```css
button.btn-search {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  background: none;
}
button.btn-search:hover {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: blue;
}
input {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="input-group input-lg">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-search"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

      </button>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```